# Run failed tests first during rerun in Hudson

Tags: unit-testing, hudson, jenkins

I have a long-running unit test job in hudson. If some tests fail I want to run them first and not wait for other tests to run before them (to see, have I fixed them, or not). 
Is it possible to setup this in Hudson?
Thanks.

Comment: Unit tests are not meant to be long-running, by the way. Do they touch a database / web service? In that case you can rebadge them, as integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue before, here is my solution.

1. You can write a standalone program to run a list of unit test cases. (In my case, I wrote a Java main class to run Junit manually.)
2. Create a job that can run with "Trigger builds remotely" and pass the list from the url
3. Use [Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) to grab the failure result from Hudson's "Test Result"
4. Use [Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) to trigger the job from "Trigger builds remotely" with the failure list.

By the way, you can also send a mail with the result when the rerun testing failure, and then you can just check mail if the test is real "failure".

Note that the Selenium is not necessary if you have another choice.

Comment: How you use selenium to grab the failures from Hudson?

Comment: You can use Hudson's "Publish JUnit test result report" to generate a testing report, and then use Selenium to grab that page, it will be placed under the URL. /hudson/job/Job_Name/Build_Number/testReport/

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible in Hudson, but if you're using Eclipse (sorry I'm assuming you're using Java), you can run the tests, and re-run them using 'Rerun Test - Failures First'.