# How to make Jenkins run failed tests first, and upon successful completion, run all the tests again?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

Let's pretend that we have a jenkins job called `functional-tests`. I am looking for a way to configure this job, so that when it fails due to one or more of the tests failing, on the next run (e.g. triggered by a commit) it only runs the failed tests.

Now if this run was successful, it automatically triggers another build of the job to run all the tests.

However if the run was unsuccessful, it will continue to only run the tests that were failed in the previous run.

I think the only thing I need, is to pass the state of the previous build as well as the tests that were failed to the current job.

We are using Maven and Surefire for the build.

Comment: This Hudson question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249655/run-failed-tests-first-during-rerun-in-hudson